# Trouble building Roslib (diamondback) on 64-bit OSX Snow Leopard

Tags: ros, macos-snowleopard, 64bit, osx, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just pulled down the latest ros-turtle, diamond back and it doesn't seem to build on OSX 64-bit. I'm following along on the install [wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/OSX).

And it fails to build with:

Finished

the output log says:

cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[rosbuild] Building package roslib
[rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
[rosbuild] Including /Users/mike/Code/ros/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /Users/mike/Code/ros/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /Users/mike/Code/ros/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/mike/Code/ros/ros/core/roslib/build
cd build && make -l4
Scanning dependencies of target rospack_genmsg_libexe
[  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
Scanning dependencies of target rosbuild_precompile
[  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
Scanning dependencies of target roslib
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/roslib.dir/src/package.o
In file included from /usr/include/architecture/i386/math.h:626,
                 from /usr/include/math.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cmath:54,
                 from /opt/local/include/boost/config/no_tr1/cmath.hpp:21,
                 from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_config.hpp:15,
                 from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_system.hpp:13,
                 from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/ptime.hpp:12,
                 from /opt/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_types.hpp:12,
                 from /opt/local/include/boost/thread/thread_time.hpp:11,
                 from /opt/local/include/boost/thread/locks.hpp:12,
                 from /opt/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:12,
                 from /opt/local/include/boost/thread/mutex.hpp:16,
                 from /Users/mike/Code/ros/ros/core/roslib/src/package.cpp:37:
/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:108:14: warning: #warning Building for Intel with Mac OS X Deployment Target

Has anyone else seen anything like this?  Any help or pointers to a workaround would be **much** appreciated.

### Cheers,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9291/trouble-building-roslib-(diamondback)-on-64-bit-osx-snow-leopard./) by [Marrok](https://answers.ros.org/users/238/marrok/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2011-03-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marrok](https://answers.ros.org/users/238/marrok/) on 2011-03-08**:
'rosmake roslib' is the part I'm having issue with.

**Comment by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on 2011-03-05**:
I'm running ok on the same system. Which step is giving you this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My roslib compile works out-of-the-box (diamondback, 10.6, 64-bit).  These lines look very suspicious:

```
/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:108:14: warning: #warning Building for Intel with Mac OS X Deployment Target < 10.4 is invalid.
Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libroslib.dylib
ld: -rpath can only be used when targeting Mac OS X 10.5 or later
```

Building for Intel for Mac OS X < 10.4?  It looks like your build environment is screwed up.  Maybe you have MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET set in your environment?

---

Originally posted by [Paul Vernaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/240/paul-vernaza/) with karma: 181 on 2011-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marrok](https://answers.ros.org/users/238/marrok/) on 2011-03-11**:
There must have been cruft from a migration I did from an old Mac, I was able to get it to build, although I did have to tweak the install_dirs() in rosboost_cfg.py it seemed to always return the empty string.

**Comment by [Paul Vernaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/240/paul-vernaza/) on 2011-03-08**:
This might also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211387/python-build-problem-on-mac-os-10-6-snow-leopard

**Comment by [Paul Vernaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/240/paul-vernaza/) on 2011-03-08**:
I'm actually building on the same model with no problems.  Maybe cmake is incorrectly setting the MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET?  You can try checking build/CMakeCache.txt (search for OSX) to see if it detects something weird.

**Comment by [Marrok](https://answers.ros.org/users/238/marrok/) on 2011-03-08**:
I'm also building on the latest rev of Mac Book Pro released  on February 24, 2011.

**Comment by [Marrok](https://answers.ros.org/users/238/marrok/) on 2011-03-08**:
I do not have MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET set.  Setting it to 10.6 does not seem to help.